# Have z-index issue with IE bug - CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, z-index

I am struggling with z-index for popup (newsletter signup) and it is still underneath the navigation and its dropdown. I googled and found out that relative + zindex gives IE bug but I added in z-index and they either go under or top of each other. Right now I cannot figure why it is behaving weird.

I am wondering whether the header and the navigation are conflicting with each other in z-index? Any suggestion or anything will be appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To `#header`, add `z-index: 101`.

It's `101` because *something* has a `z-index` of `100`: I suspect it's `div.col-left`.

I forget the exact details of the IE bug in question, but the fix in this case is applying a higher `z-index` value to the parent element.

Comment: thank you for saving my day! but how come #header is top on col-left?

Comment: It's an IE7 bug. Here's a [blog post](http://brenelz.com/blog/squish-the-internet-explorer-z-index-bug/) about it.

Comment: yes i found that blog post online but i tried everywhere adding z-index and it didn't work well for me (T_T) anyway you are super helpful thanks.